# How to pass a Class as an function parameter

Tags: java, arrays, class, object, parameters

I know this has been asked before, but I couldn't quite understand/the answers didn't help me, so I would appreciate some help on this matter, as I'm starting to learn Java.

I want to create a function that counts the instances of a class and returns me a number, for example i have:

```
Public class A{}
Public class A.a extends A{}
Public class A.b extends A{}
```

I have an array of A[] that has instances of A, A.a and A.b and I want to count the instances of A, A.a or A.b in that array, so i created these functions:

```
int countA.a(A[] array){
int counter = 0;
  for(int i = 0; i < array.length; i++){
    if(array[i] instanceof A.a){
      counter++;
    }
  }
  return counter;
}

int countA.b(A[] array){
int counter = 0;
  for(int i = 0; i < array.length; i++){
    if(array[i] instanceof A.b){
      counter++;
    }
  }
  return counter;
}
```

My question is, how can i do something like this:

```
int countInstances(A[] array, class n){
int counter = 0;
  for(int i = 0; i < array.length; i++){
    if(array[i] instanceof n){
      counter++;
    }
  }
  return counter;
}
```

Thanks for your patience!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [`Class`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html) class:

```
int countInstances(A[] array, Class<? extends A> n){
```

And instead of `instanceof`, you should use the [`isInstance`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#isInstance-java.lang.Object-) method in the `Class` class.

```
if(n.isInstance(array[i])){
  counter++;
}
```

Usage:

```
int count = countInstances(someArray, SubclassOfA.class);
```

Comment: If `n` is `A.class` and the `array` contains only subclasses of `A`, wouldn't the count still be returned as the length of `array` (since the subclasses are an `A`)?

Comment: ```List.class.isInstance(new ArrayList());
List.class.isInstance(new LinkedList<>());``` are both true

Comment: @AndrewS that’s true of the `instanceof` operator as well.

Answer (score 0):

you can get the `Class` of a type by using `A.class`, or from an instance by using

```
A myA = new A();
Class<?> clazzOfA = myA.getClass();
```

and pass it as a parameter of type `Class<?>`

So in your example, something like:

```
int instances = countInstances(myArray, A.b.class);

int countInstances(A[] array, Class<?> n){
int counter = 0;
  for(int i = 0; i < array.length; i++){
    if(array[i].getClass() == n){
      counter++;
    }
  }
  return counter;
}
```

Some examples:

```
boolean hasSameClass(Object type, Class<?> n){
    return type.getClass() == n;
}

hasSameClass(new LinkedList(), ArrayList.class);    // false
hasSameClass(new ArrayList(), LinkedList.class);    // false
hasSameClass(new ArrayList(), ArrayList.class);     // true
hasSameClass(new ArrayList(), List.class);          // false
```